# keeping the same stylesheet and display data same page issue

Tags: php, html, css, integration

[image: search input form]

**Code for index.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<?php 
include ('recherchecommande.php') ;
?>
<title>Pâtisserie Baya</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles/960.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles/text.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="themes/brown/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles/sample.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles/table.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dapur.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="warp" >
  <div id="main" class="container_16">
    <div id="header" class="grid_16">
      <div id="logo" class="grid_4 alpha">
        <h1><a href="index.html">DapurKue</a></h1>
        <h2>Famously Delicious</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="headright" class="grid_7 prefix_5 omega">
        <h3 class="login"><a href="login.html">Sign up</a> / <a href="login.html">Login</a></h3>

        <p><span class="vChart"><a href="shoppingcart.html">View Cart</a></span> <span class="cOut"><a href="checkout.html">Checkout</a></span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainMenu" class="grid_16">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cakes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Order &amp; Delivery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="reclamation.html">Reclamation</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="stickySearch" class="grid_16">
      <div class="stickyNews grid_12 alpha">
        <p>Valentine’s BrownieCheese Special Package. <em>Free Delivery.</em> <a href="#" class="bookMan">More &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="search grid_4 omega">
        <form action="#" method="get">
          <input type="text" value="Type your keyword" id="s" name="s" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Type your keyword') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Type your keyword';}" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="products grid_16">
      <div class="productsWarp" id="style1"><a href="mailto:someone@example.com"><img src="images\email.png"></a></div>
      <div id="style2" /> </div>
      <div id ="style3">
      <h3>Recherche par numero de commande</h3>
       <p> Searcch button</p>

<form action="recherchecommande.php?go" id="commandeForm" method="post">
<input placeholder="Numero de commande.." id="form2" type="text" name="numero"> 
     <input type="submit" name="submit" style="display: none" /><br>


</form>
</div>

       <div id="style1"></div>



    </div>
    <div class="productThumb ">
      <ul>

        <li class="grid_2 alpha"><a href="#"><img src="images/cake1.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="60" /></a></li>
        <li class="grid_2"><a href="#"><img src="images/cake2.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="60" /></a></li>
        <li class="grid_2"><a href="#"><img src="images/cake3.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="60" /></a></li>
        <li class="grid_2"><a href="#"><img src="images/cake4.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="60" /></a></li>
        <li class="grid_2"><a href="#"><img src="images/cake5.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="60" /></a></li>
        <li class="grid_2"><a href="#"><img src="images/cake6.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="60" /></a></li>
        <li class="grid_2"><a href="#"><img src="images/cake7.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="60" /></a></li>
        <li class="grid_2 omega"><a href="#"><img src="images/cake8.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="60" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="fresh">
  <div class="container_16">
    <div id="freshCake" class="grid_16">
      <div class="grid_1 alpha"> <a class="prevButton">&laquo;</a></div>
      <div class="headLine grid_14">
        <h3>Fresh from the oven</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="grid_1 omega"> <a class="nextButton">&raquo;</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="newCakes">
      <div class="scroller">
        <div class="newCake"><a href="product-details.html" class="grid_4"><img src="images/freshCake1.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="120" /></a></div>
        <div class="newCake"><a href="product-details.html" class="grid_4"><img src="images/freshCake2.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="120" /></a></div>
        <div class="newCake"><a href="product-details.html" class="grid_4"><img src="images/freshCake3.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="120" /></a></div>
        <div class="newCake"><a href="product-details.html" class="grid_4"><img src="images/freshCake4.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="120" /></a></div>
        <div class="newCake"><a href="product-details.html" class="grid_4"><img src="images/freshCake5.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="120" /></a></div>
        <div class="newCake"><a href="product-details.html" class="grid_4"><img src="images/freshCake6.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="120" /></a></div>
        <div class="newCake"><a href="product-details.html" class="grid_4"><img src="images/freshCake7.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="120" /></a></div>
        <div class="newCake"><a href="product-details.html" class="grid_4"><img src="images/freshCake8.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="120" /></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="richContent">
  <div class="container_16">
    <div class="popularCakes grid_4">
      <h4>Popular Cakes</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ultimate Choco Brownie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mokakokoa Brownie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CoffeeBrown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delicacheese</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Berries Cheesecake</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="recommended grid_4">
      <h4>Recommended</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ultimate Choco Brownie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mokakokoa Brownie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CoffeeBrown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delicacheese</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Berries Cheesecake</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="specialOffer grid_4">
      <h4>Special Offer</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ultimate Choco Brownie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mokakokoa Brownie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CoffeeBrown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delicacheese</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Berries Cheesecake</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="orderPhone grid_4">
      <h4><em>Order by Phone</em> <span>20.321.331</span></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="richContent2">
  <div class="container_16">
    <div class="fromBlog grid_4">
      <h4>From the blog</h4>
      <h5>New Recipes in Our Basket</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. vivamus tempor justo sit amet metus cursus consequat. Nulla viverra, felis vel accumsan fermentum... <a href="#" class="bookMan">more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="corporateInfo grid_4">
      <h4>Corporate Info</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Term &amp; Conditions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Franchise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="storeDelivery grid_4">
      <h4>Store &amp; Delivery</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Store Locator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delivery Terms &amp; Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delivery Coverage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gift Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Track my order</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="socialNet grid_4">
      <h4>Keep in touch</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="twitter">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="feed">Feed</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container_16">
    <div class="copyright grid_16">
      <p class="left">Copyright &copy; 2016, Athenas, All Rights Reserved</p>
      <p class="right">Design by <a href="http://tokokoo.com/">Tokokoo</a> &amp; <a href="http://www.instantshift.com/">instantShift</a></p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code for search.php**

```
<?php

 include ('connect.php') ;
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "baya");
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  if(isset($_GET['go'])){

   $cmd=$_POST['numero'];

  $sql="SELECT * from commande WHERE  commande_id LIKE ".$cmd."";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql); 

      $number=$result->num_rows ;
    echo "





" ;

      if ($number==1)
      {   
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
          $commande_id  =$row['commande_id'];
          $description=$row['description'];
          $status=$row['status'];
          $report=$row['report'] ;




  echo "
  <table border=1> 

<thead>

<tr>
<th>commande_id</th>
<th>description</th>
<th>status</th>
<th>report</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tr>


<td>$commande_id</td>
<td>$description</td>
<td>$status</td>
<td>$report</td>

</tr>



";


header('location reclamation.html') ;


  }
      }

  else{
  echo  "<p>Command id n'existe pas</p>";
  }

  }
  }

  else{
      echo "search query is empty" ;
}

?>
```

**I want to show the query in the same page not another one**

*For example if i type 1 it should returns this query from database*
[image]

not to show the result in another page ..
Is it possible to show the result at the bottom of the Search button with
the same style sheet !

Thank you everybody for helping !
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your form action attribute like this

```
<form action="" mehtode="post">
```

and write the php code on the same page to process the data send.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     //process the form
     //output
     // etc....
 }
?>
```

Please post the code sample. So we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other php file with includes with the same css and html structure of you other php, or you can use Ajax with javascript for get the data and then show it.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Comment: there is no other possible to include php file into html ?

Comment: No once the server send the php file , the brower "client side" can't execute php code.